# How to connect image apache/hive with image apache/hadoop?

Tags: docker, hadoop, docker-compose, hive

I have docker-compose.yml file. How i can connect apache hive with apache hadoop? I want create table on hive. Extract data from api and load into hadoop hdfs. Have another way like create DockerFile set up config Apache hive connect to Hadoop ................................................................

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 'metastore_db'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'hive'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'hive'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - hive-db:/var/lib/postgresql

  namenode:
    image: apache/hadoop:3
    container_name: namenode
    hostname: namenode
    command: ["hdfs", "namenode"]
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
      - 8020:8020
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    environment:
        ENSURE_NAMENODE_DIR: "/tmp/hadoop-root/dfs/name"
    volumes:
      - ./data/namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name

  datanode:
    image: apache/hadoop:3
    container_name: datanode
    command: ["hdfs", "datanode"]
    ports:
      - 9864:9864
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    volumes:
      - ./data/datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data

  resourcemanager:
    image: apache/hadoop:3
    hostname: resourcemanager
    command: ["yarn", "resourcemanager"]
    ports:
        - 8088:8088
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    volumes:
      - ./test.sh:/opt/test.sh

  nodemanager:
    image: apache/hadoop:3
    command: ["yarn", "nodemanager"]
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  metastore:
    image: apache/hive:4.0.0-alpha-2
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - namenode
      - resourcemanager
      - datanode
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: metastore
    hostname: metastore
    environment:
      DB_DRIVER: postgres
      SERVICE_NAME: 'metastore'
      # HIVE_CUSTOM_CONF_DIR: ./hive_custom_conf 
      SERVICE_OPTS: '-Xmx1G 
        -Djavax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=org.postgresql.Driver
        -Djavax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/metastore_db
        -Djavax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName=hive
        -Djavax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword=hive'
    ports:
      - '9083:9083'
    volumes:
      - warehouse:/opt/hive/data/warehouse
      # - /opt/hive/conf:./hive_custom_conf

  hiveserver2:
    image: apache/hive:4.0.0-alpha-2
    depends_on:
      - metastore
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: hiveserver2
    environment:
      HIVE_SERVER2_THRIFT_PORT: 10000
      SERVICE_OPTS: '-Xmx1G -Dhive.metastore.uris=thrift://metastore:9083'
      IS_RESUME: 'true'
      SERVICE_NAME: 'hiveserver2'
    ports:
      - '10000:10000'
      - '10002:10002'
    volumes:
      - warehouse:/opt/hive/data/warehouse

volumes:
  warehouse:
  hive-db:

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

hadoop.env

```
CORE-SITE.XML_fs.default.name=hdfs://namenode
CORE-SITE.XML_fs.defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000
CORE-SITE.XML_hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts=*
CORE-SITE.XML_hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups=*

HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.namenode.rpc-address=namenode:8020
HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.replication=1
HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check=false
HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.webhdfs.enabled=true
HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.fs.defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000
HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.permissions.enabled=false

MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.framework.name=yarn
MAPRED-SITE.XML_yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.map.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.reduce.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.reduce.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.reduce.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx4096m
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=8192
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx3072m
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx6144m

YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.resourcemanager.hostname=resourcemanager
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled=false
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.delete.debug-delay-sec=600
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled=false
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.aux-services=mapreduce_shuffle
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.timeline-service.enabled=true
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.mapreduce.map.output.compress=true
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=16384
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores=8
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage=98.5
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir=/app-logs

CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications=10000
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent=0.1
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues=default
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.capacity=100
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit-factor=1
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-capacity=100
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.state=RUNNING
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_submit_applications=*
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_administer_queue=*
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.node-locality-delay=40
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings=
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings-override.enable=false
```

Connect Apache hive image with Apache hadoop image.

Answer (score 0):

Hive acts like a regular Hadoop client. You need to mount core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, and yarn-site.xml files on its HADOOP_HOME environment variable path, and point values like fs.defaultFS (core-site.xml) at the namenode container and the yarn resource manager address (yarn-site.xml), then configure the execution engine for mapreduce or tez as well as your JDBC/JDO configurations (hive-site.xml)

Reminder that you shouldn't need HDFS, YARN, or Postgres. The default Derby metastore of the Hive image will still allow you to run Hive queries against its local filesystem. And SparkSQL / FlinkSQL could also query data on your machine without any of these containers. More specifically, Hive will not be fast, assuming you have 8G of RAM, since you're running 7 containers, and each takes about 1GB each.

Comment: I read document of apache hive docker image. Just replace file hdfs-site.xml or yarn-site.xml.

Link: https://hive.apache.org/developement/quickstart/

Comment: Correct. You can copy some of those files out of the datanode / nodemanager containers

Comment: I try building ETL connect using data warehouse. I try build docker compose with airflow, hive, hadoop to build data warehouse. Is this right way to build data warehouse?

Comment: Thank you. I will try copy hdfs-site.xml and yarn-site.xml into hive container.

Comment: You could also build ETL pipelines in airflow, with Spark / Flink, and MinIO. Or just use Nifi/Streamsets/Talend/Knime to replace Airflow... But airflow requires a database, anyway, so you'd already have Postgres for that

Comment: Thank you about another framework replace Airflow. I understand that Hive is just middleware for execution on Hadoop through HQL commands. And for storing data, it needs to connect to a Postgres database for storage.

Comment: Right, though you don't need Hive Server... Spark, Flink, Trino, Impala, etc can connect to Hive **Metastore**